# AsRock 970 Extreme4 motherboard compatibility

Tags: compatibility

Is asrock 970 extreme4 compatibility with ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar board like the one in the question, and I have no issues running Ubuntu on it.  I installed Ubuntu 13.04 from a USB flash drive, and it works flawlessly.

Now depending on what display adapter you use, you may need a drive for that.